# Vanilla javascript: How to access DOM elements properties through a function parameter?

Tags: javascript

I am very new to Javascript (to programing in general also). I am trying to make a function that will take in a parameter (the DOM element's name) to access its DOM properties.

For example, I have multiple DOM elements created beforehand:

```
const aGatherPlants = document.createElement('p');
aGatherPlants.className = 'gather-plants btn btn-medium btn-dark mrgn-b';
aGatherPlants.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`Plants [${costGatherPlants}]`));
aGatherPlants.style.display = 'none';
aGatheringTab.appendChild(aGatherPlants);

const aGatherWood = document.createElement('p');
aGatherWood.className = 'gather-wood btn btn-medium btn-dark mrgn-b';
aGatherWood.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`Wood [${costGatherWood}]`));
aGatherWood.style.display = 'none';
aGatheringTab.appendChild(aGatherWood);
```

My goal is to access those element's properties, such as `element.style`, `element.appendChild`, `element.addEventListeners`, etc. in a function.

```
function functionName(property){
  property.style.display = 'none';
}

functionName('aGatherPlants');
```

Obviously, it doesn't work and browser console is logging `cannot access property .style of undefined`.

I want to make a single function to access all DOM elements created, instead of having to hard code every single one of them.

Can anyone help out a newbie here ? If you need more information, please let me know.

Comment: Aren't you trying to access property by name?  `function getProp(pName, obj){return obj[pName];}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i can see you are passing a string instead of the variable you want  in the function, remember that, when you put something between ' ' or " " you are saying "this value is a string type value" so watch for this in the future.

```
function functionName(property){
    property.style.display = 'none';
}
//Here you are passing a string as paremeter
//but you want to pass the const aGatherPlants
functionName('aGatherPlants');
//So you need to do this instead
functionName(aGatherPlants);
```

Comment: This is the solution for what you are looking :) What you also could do is to just reselect the element you want to edit `function(p) {document.querySelector(p).style...}` and than do `function('gather-plants btn btn-medium btn-dark mrgn-b')`